# url hash fix needed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use an ajax code in my site. My problem is that I want only to use last part of the link.. otherwise the hash value becomes as here :

```
http://localhos./~ytsejam/wlog/public/#http://localhos./~ytsejam/wlog/public/index.php/
```

This is my line and ajax code for hashing :

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
```

and here is my menu item in the source

```
<li><a href="http://localhos./~ytsejam/wlog/public/index.php/abouts">HAKKIMIZDA</a></li>
```

.

How can I change subsrt value to work here?

Comment: Which part of the `href` attribute do you want to set the `location.hash` to? Perhaps read the [`substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) documentation

Comment: I want the last part which is after public/index.php. I counted there are 48 characters which I dont want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than parsing URL strings, I suggest you be more explicit in assigning data.

Try something like this

```
<a href="http://localhos./~ytsejam/wlog/public/index.php/abouts"
   data-hash="abouts">HAKKIMIZDA</a>
```

Then use the data attribute in your event handler

```
window.location.hash = $(this).data('hash');
```

### Update

Using [`HTML::link_to_route()`](http://laravel.com/api/class-Laravel.HTML.html#_link_to_route), you would do something like

```
{{HTML::link_to_route('abouts', 'HAKKIMIZDA', array(), array(
    'data-hash' => 'abouts'
))}}
```

I suggest you become familiar with the documentation for your framework of choice.

Comment: I use laravel framework. The links are shown like this in the source  <li>{{HTML::link_to_route('abouts', 'HAKKIMIZDA');}}</li>

Comment: I check documentation and tutorials , but I started to confuse things. because you can manage an event by many choices , so all solutions are mixed that is why I am asking to use the correct way thank you Phil.